# Seeming contradiction if Rabbi Yochanan had kids

Tags: amoroim, children

There's a well-known *gemarra* in [Berachos 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.5b.9?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) that says that Rabbi Yochanan buried ten of his sons.

There's also another story with Rabbi Yochanan in [Yevamos 96b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.96b.18?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). He was upset that his student didn't quote a teaching of his in his name, and the *gemarra* says the reason is because when someone quotes the Torah of a deceased Rabbi, their lips move in the grave. The obvious question is that Rabbi Yochanan was alive at the time, so why was he upset? The [Eitz Yosef ad. loc.](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47607&st=&pgnum=354) explains that since Rabbi Yochanan didn't have any kids, as per the *gemarra* in Berachos 5b, he was considered like he was dead (see [Nedarim 64b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.64b.6?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)). It would appear then that all of Rabbi Yochanan's children died.

However, the *gemarra* in [Kiddushin 71b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.71b.3?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that Rabbi Yochanan had a daughter that he tried to marry off to his student Zeiri. This would appear to be a contradiction, as we see he had at least one living child. Does anyone point this out? I can think of a few resolutions, but I don't know if they're correct. Perhaps his daughter died as well, and this was before she died, and in the Yevamos story he had no children at all? Or perhaps the concept of being without children being considered dead is referring to male children (I hope not)?

Comment: Maybe [Tosafos to Yevamos 65a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Yevamot.65a.6.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is a clue: שטוענת שרוצה שיהא לה זכר דמי שאין לו בנים חשוב כמת. I believe he means zecher, but perhaps only a male child can provide a zecher? [This sefer](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/141268/p/479/t/0.43193083188505431234/fs/g8TWMJjjojkGVwzsqjllOjRzOXivjZtfbBgIpvcrjpi7/start/24/end/42/c) has Tosafos saying שיהא לה בן זכר, and infers but not a daughter. Although that sefer cites the page wrong, so not surprising they got the text wrong as well.

Answer (score 7):

Tosafot on the spot in Berachot seems to assume that daughters don’t count, citing the very passage in Kiddushin as proof:

> ואי משום בנות ר׳ יוחנן נמי הוו ליה בנות בפרק בתרא דקדושין

Comment: Tosafos there is discussing something else...ייסורים של אהבה. Although I do see someone else noticed rabbi Yochanan having kids :)

Comment: @robev But in context the point is whether בנות remove one from the category of אין לו בנים.

Comment: Though the proof does seem a little odd, even contradictory to the Gemara in Berachos itself — perhaps that’s why the Bach emends it. I also recall the Tzlach having a pshat in this Tosafos, but don’t have access at the moment.

Comment: He says that not having ever had kids isn't necessarily yissurim shel ahava since it could just be a medical problem or mazal. However, if a person had a daughter, but no sons, that's only either due to sin or yissurim shel ahava. A tzaddik can't be due to the former, only the latter